# BeautifulSoup UnicodeEncodeError: ascii codec

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do some parsing with BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

r = requests.get('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/')

page_text = r.text.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_text, 'lxml')

print(soup.find_all('p'))
```

I can't use `find_all('p')` because of `UnicodeEncodeError`. Typing just soup.p works good. I used the variable `page_text` to encode html file but it is not enough. How can I overcome this error and access all paragraphs from the site?

Comment: I run your code then don't give any error.

Comment: I'm still getting this error     `print(soup.find_all('p'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 760: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: me too, no error, even drop variable `page_text`, and change `page_text` to `r.content` in `BeautifulSoup`, it works.

Comment: Your `print()` is failing, not your BeautifulSoup code. You are printing Unicode text to a console that doesn't support the characterset.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think you got it, I'm using sublime text. Know any solutions?

Comment: @Maxxer: See [printing UTF-8 in Python 3 using Sublime Text 3](//stackoverflow.com/q/39576308)